# Can I use selenium IDE for flash button?

Tags: flash, selenium

Hi I am new to Selenium IDE. Now I am testing a site with selenium IDE, I have a problem with flash pages, when I testing flash pages selenium didn't record anything, I read lot of tutorials, they said selenium IDE doesn't record flash pages, Any method can I use for getting the flash button id(submit_btn)?

Comment: Selenium cannot be used for Flash:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655862/flash-automation-using-selenium

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, I am testing a project like a social networking, I am using Selenium for my testing, In my project, I can set a video conference, that time only the flash page will work, When I test the video conference meeting, I need to access the flash page, So I need any other way to access the flash page, I don't know about the Selenium RC or other related selenium tools for accessing flash, Do you know any other selenium related tools for accessing flash pages? Thanks again

Comment: check selenium webdriver http://seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I can use Selenium RC for testing flash pages, I found [abode tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flash_selenium.html) for testing flash pages with Selenium RC, and [Flash-Selenium](http://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/) also helpful tool.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the [Selenium Chrome WebDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) was able to interact with Flash player.